# Layer multiple <div>'s on top of one another each with different background

Tags: html, css

I want to stack one division on top of another each with different background. the background, ofcourse will be transparent (.png). This is to recreate an effect of a pattern on an image and avoid loading an entire 1366 x 768 image.

my html is somewhat like this

```
<body>
  <div id="firstLayer">
    <div id="secondLayer">
         <div id="mainContent">
          main page content 
         </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I have a radial gradient for the `body`, the `#firstLayer` contains the main logo, and the `#secondLayer` must consist the transparent pattern.

my first try at css was somewhat like this

```
#secondLayer{
    background: url("../images/crtPattern.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

But the pattern doesnt show up at all. How can i bring this `#secondLayer` on top of `#firstLayer` but just below the `#mainContent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give width and height to `#secondLayer` like this [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cQppc/1/)

```
#secondLayer{
    background: url("../images/crtPattern.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Why z-index is needed here when mainContainer is a child of secondLayer?

Comment: @Dipaks just removed before you commented :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do this -

```
#firstLayer{ background: red; height: 500px; }
#secondLayer{ background: green; opacity: 0.6; filter:alpha(opacity=60); height: 300px; }
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vW9bn/)

Answer (score 1):

Width and height are definitely required if you have no DIV content. If that doesn't fix the problem for you:

Check image paths, can you load the same image using the same image path in an IMG tag?

Is your stylesheet inline or loaded as a separate file - this will affect relative paths to the image file.

Is your webserver case-sensitive? Does the case of your path match the image?

Hope this helps.